# Proving that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\,(\ln (2\pi x+\frac{\pi }{2})-\ln 2\pi x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Hello I am studying for an upcoming exam and I came to this question:

> A) Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\,(\ln (2\pi
>   x+\frac{\pi }{2})-\ln 2\pi x)=0$.
>
> B) Use part A of the question to show that $\sin (e^x)$ is not
>   uniformly continuous.

I am completely stumped - I do not see how to prove A or how it helps with B, Can someone please help me with this question? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hint for a): $\ln a-\ln b=\ln{a\over b}$.  Hint for b): What is $|\sin e^{\ln(2\pi x+\pi/2)} -\sin e^{\ln 2\pi x}|$ and what does a) tell you about $|\ln(2\pi x+\pi/2)-\ln 2\pi x|$?

Comment: What does $\ln (2\pi > x + \frac{\pi}{2})$ mean?

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the tips guys - I will try to solve using them :)

Comment: OK, I see, that was a typo.

Comment: @WNY It was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Ok, A solved Thanks to David's tip. Now on to B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint for a):

Use the identity $\ln a−\ln b=\ln(a/b)$.

Hint for b):

What is $|\sin e^{\ln(2\pi x+\pi/2)}−\sin e^{\ln(2\pi x)}|$ and what does part a) tell you about $|\ln(2\pi x+\pi/2)−\ln(2\pi x)|$?

Warning: solution follows.

For part a), use the difference rules for logarithms:
$$
\ln(2\pi x+{\textstyle{\pi\over2}})-\ln(2\pi x)=\ln{ 2\pi x+{\pi\over2} \over 2\pi x  }\quad
\buildrel{x\rightarrow\infty}\over{\longrightarrow }\quad\ln (1)=0.
$$

For part b), note that, for $x$ an  integer
$$
\bigl|\,\sin e^{ \ln(2\pi x+{\textstyle{\pi\over2}})}  -\sin e^{\ln 2\pi x}\,\bigr|
=\bigl |\,\sin (2\pi x+{\textstyle{\pi\over2}})  -\sin (2\pi x)\,\bigr |=1.
$$

Towards showing that $f(x)=\sin(e^x)$ is not uniformly continuous,
let $\epsilon=1$ and suppose $\delta>0$.

By part a), we can select an integer $x$ so that
 $|\ln(2\pi x+{\textstyle{\pi\over2}})-\ln(2\pi x)|<\delta$.

But by part b),
$$\bigl|\,\sin e^{ \ln(2\pi x+{\pi\over2})}  -\sin e^{\ln( 2\pi x)}\,\bigr|=1= \epsilon.$$

So, we have demonstrated that for for $\epsilon=1$, and any $\delta>0$, we can find two points $x_1=\ln(2\pi x+{\pi\over2}) $ and $x_2=\ln(2\pi x)$ such that   $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$, yet $\bigl|\,\sin e^{x_1} -\sin e^{x_2}\,\bigr|\ge\epsilon$.
This shows that $\sin(e^x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) Have a nice day